# GIT deleted my local files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control, github

I have a pretty big problem. I am going through a Ruby on Rails tutorial, and they have suggested that I use GIT for version control. I have never used it before, and through the tutorial I don't think I used it right. Here is some back story.

I created a new project, and then I created a new Github repository. I named them the same thing, and I pushed my project to that repository. I then looked at Github, and all of my project files were there. I then went through a few chapters of the tutorial, and followed there instructions for pushing files to GIT. After awhile I realized, that none of my files were being uploaded. I didn't really care, so I went on with the tutorial. Still pushing files to GIT even though they were not showing up.

**IMPORTANT** 
My Github repository only had the few files from when I first created it, the project on my local machine has a MANY more files. In the last chapter of the tutorial I was able to follow, it told me to do these commands:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Finish layout and routes"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge filling-in-layout
```

Once I did those commands, my project located on my local machine lost ALL of the files I created in the last couple of days. My guess is that Github replaced my files from my local machine with the files on Github (Just the files created when I started the project)

I think I have been adding files to GIT on my local machine since the folder '~/.git/logs/HEAD' has all of the commits I made, with what looks like GIT file numbers.

Any help would save me so many hours. 
Thanks, -Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You committed some changes, then got the old version and reverted to it by issuing "git merge filling-in-layout". (you created a branch "filling-in-layout")

whatever you do DO NOT -> `git reset --hard` <- DO NOT.

what does "git branch" say?

do this:

```
git checkout master (or one of the others)
```

and look which one is yours. ;)

Comment: When I do that a list of 4 things come up. filling-in-layout, master, modeling-users (with a star next to it) and static-pages

Comment: It seems very possible that a lot of the commits you think you are missing were made to those other branches, and are still sitting in there. Use gitk to get a lovely diagram of what you've been doing.

Comment: Ok, I did gitk, and that opened up WISH, all of the files I am missing are listed in the patch, what should I do to get them back. Also when you say cd <some_other_dir> do you mean, any dir. Or a particular one? Thanks for your help BTW!

Comment: When I do 'git checkout master' it says "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: <list of files>Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches." Thanks for your quick responses, I can see that we are getting closer and closer :)

Comment: stash your changes means "commit what you have changed at your current branch"

Comment: Should I do 'git commit -m "whatever" before 'git checkout'?

Comment: yes, "finish up at the current branch" which was created by your call to merge.

Comment: When I did that, nothing happened so I checked gitk again and it no longer shows the files. Do you know what might have happened? Hopefully I did not screw anything up. Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I just walked through the steps you told me before and I now see the files. But I am still having a problem with the git checkout. Even when I use git commit before, it does not allow me to checkout.

Comment: sounds odd.. any errors? read this: http://www.gitguys.com/topics/switching-branches-without-committing/

Comment: When I just used 'git checkout master' it outputted "Already on 'master'" <new line> "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits."

Comment: ohh.. then your files should be back

Comment: Should the files appear in my project folder?

Comment: If you switch to the proper branch, the files should be back. on which branch did you find your files with gitk?

Comment: When I checkout to master is says it's deleting all of the files. And modifying the ones I already have.

Comment: wasn't master the branch you saw in gitk? maybe gitk can switch to that branch for you too? (i never used it)

Comment: When it lists the files after 'checkout master' there are one of two letters (d & m) I know m = merged, what does d mean?

Comment: deleted. i assumed master was the branch containing your files, checkout the one that has them.

Comment: I went to gitk, and choose the commit with all of my files, it says the branches are "filling-in-layout, master, modeling-users, and static-pages. This is all so hard for me to explain, sorry that it's taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

Erase github from your mind. It is irrelevant. The git repository is on your machine, inside your rails app folder. That is the beauty of git. So everything you have ever committed to git while working from that folder is there. It's possible you made some mistake along the way, or that the tutorial instructed you incorrectly, but you can look through all your commits with "git log", and then just go back to the point where things were good: checkout that commit (thus recreating the situation as it was at that moment), and pick up again from there.

Pedagogically I would suggest that you not try to learn git and rails simultaneously. They are both big and interesting, but they are completely orthogonal (that's fancy talk for "they have nothing to do with one another"). If you want to learn rails, learn rails. If you want to learn git, learn git. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Based on his description, I'm pretty sure he's using [railstutorial.org,](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top) which for what it's worth integrates git, rails, and heroku knowledge quite well.